# .net unit test project with CSV datasource not reading in values correctly

Tags: .net, unit-testing, csv, datasource

I have a Unit Test project in .net 4.0.  One of the test methods reads in a CSV file.  Unfortunately, some of the values in the csv file are not being read.  I think what is happening is that .net is choosing what type a column is and ignoring any values that do not fit within that type.  For example, I may have a column where 90% of the values are numbers, but the other 10% are numbers with letters.  The numbers with letters are not coming through.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the attribute on top of my test method

```
        [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\test.csv", "test#csv",  DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("MyProject.Tests\\TestData\\Test.csv"), TestMethod()]
```

Thanks!
AFrieze

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the values in the mixed-type column in quotation marks. E.g.

```
AllNumeric,Mixed,AllString
1,"1",a
2,"2b",b
```

Alternatively, you can create a file named Schema.ini in the same directory as the csv file to specify the type, as mentioned below.
http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2011/01/03/uploading-and-importing-csv-file-to-sql-server-in-asp.net.aspx